# PostgreSQL function-OID: 'my OID' where 'my' is the currently executing user-defined-function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, temp-tables, postgresql-9.2

This query returns the OID of the function whose name and signature is supplied:

```
  select 'myfunc(signature)'::regprocedure::oid;
```

But is there something in PostgreSQL plpgsql like a `myNameAndSignature()` function so we could use dynamic sql to build a statement that gets the OID of the function and then creates a temporary table with the OID appended to the name of the temp table?
The statement to execute dynamically is:

```
create temp table TT17015
```

I'm new to PostgreSQL, and maybe there's a better way to handle naming of temporary tables so the functions that use temp tables, and call each other, don't get the error that a particular temp table it is trying to delete is in use elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the OID of a function does not necessarily prevent a naming conflict. The same function could be run  multiple times in the same session.

If you are in need of a unique name, use a [`SEQUENCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createsequence.html). Run once in your database:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tt_seq;
```

Then, in your plpgsql function or `DO` statement:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
    _tbl text := 'tt' || nextval('tt_seq');
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'CREATE TEMP TABLE ' || _tbl || '(id int)';
END
$$
```

Drawback is that you have to use [**dynamic SQL**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) for dynamic identifiers. Plain SQL commands do not accept parameters for identifiers.

Comment: Good idea, and thanks for the caveat that dynamically created tablename can be used only in a dynamic SQL statement.